# rails not logined user to see their post after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using devise gem in my project.

I want to make my rails application acts like this but have some problems.

I've tried to make tmp user id so that i can change the post's user_id but it doesn't work well

Case1: (not logined user) make new posts => post is saved but not shown to user after user signs up and redirects to the sign_up session

Case2: (logined user) make new posts => shows directly

Comment: For Case1: you won't be able to assign new post to user because user is not there before sign up/login.
Solution: you have to update that post once user signed up.
For case2: You'll need to manage this in your controller's action using "current_user.posts" which only shows that user posts and that could only possible if you have that current_user scope in your controller and make sure you have made correct association.

Comment: Thanks a lot Asmita gave me many clue!! hope you have nice 2020